# Installing MS SQL Server Express 2017 with Inno Installer

Tags: inno-setup, sql-server-express

I'm desperately trying to install SQL Server Express 2017 with Inno Installer.
Within my installer I include the extracted installer files.
That means that I already executed the common SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe, to avoid the "extract-temp-folder" prompt while my installer is running.

I execute the following on the cmd:

`{somePath}\SQLEXPR_x64_ENU\setup.exe /ACTION=Install /Q /SKIPRULES=RebootRequiredCheck /SUPPRESSPRIVACYSTATEMENTNOTICE=1 /IAcceptSQLServerLicenseTerms=1 /SECURITYMODE=SQL /SAPWD=secretPW /ConfigurationFile=ConfigurationFileExpr.ini`

The install succeeds.

But when I do the same within my InnoInstaller-File like this:

`...
[Files]
Source: "SQLEXPR_x64_ENU\*"; DestDir: "{tmp}\SQLEXPR_x64_ENU"; Check: not SQLExpress_Check; Flags: recursesubdirs;
[Run]
Filename: "{tmp}\SQLEXPR_x64_ENU\setup.exe"; Description: "Installing SQL Server Express 2017..."; StatusMsg: "Installing SQL Server Express 2017...";       \
Parameters: "/ACTION=Install /Q /SKIPRULES=RebootRequiredCheck /SUPPRESSPRIVACYSTATEMENTNOTICE=1 /IAcceptSQLServerLicenseTerms=1 /SECURITYMODE=SQL /SAPWD=secretPW /ConfigurationFile=ConfigurationFileExpr.ini"; Check: not SQLExpress_Check; Flags: runascurrentuser;
...`

SQL Installer fails with the following error:

`Exception type: System.MissingMethodException
    Message: 
        Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.RoleService.Initialize(Microsoft.SQL.Chainer.Product.RolesType)'.
    HResult : 0x80131513
    Data: 
      DisableWatson = true
    Stack: 
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.BootstrapExtension.InitializeRoleServiceAction.ExecuteAction(String actionId)
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.Action.Execute(String actionId, TextWriter errorStream)
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.<>c__DisplayClasse.<ExecuteActionWithRetryHelper>b__b()
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.ExecuteActionHelper(ActionWorker workerDelegate)`

Is this a permission error?
I do not have a clue.
On cmd-shell it works, but not on InnoInstaller.

Thanks in advance for your efforts and have a nice day.

Comment: seems this can be the result of a previous corrupt installation: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/SqlServer/en-US/ef1286f9-bb31-4d1d-bdf5-afe19e285ea2/can-not-install-sql-2016?forum=sqlsetupandupgrade

Comment: If you "install" the `setup.exe` elsewhere (not `{tmp}`), does it change anything? If it still fails, does it at least work, when you manually execute the "installed" `setup.exe` (from *elsewhere*)?

Comment: @PaulColdrey: I'll check this, but I'm running this on a "clean" WIn10 VM.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl: No, it does not change anything. I also have copied it to my current installer application path. But it works, when I execute the installer from the application path with a cmd command, after the installer hast failed.

Answer (score 3):

Solution for me was provided by Gavin Lambert on the [Inno Setup Forum](http://news.jrsoftware.org/read/article.php?id=107350&group=jrsoftware.innosetup#107350) :

If you're [installing from the directory of unpacked files], you need to use `{sd}\shortname` as the `DestDir` (usually combined with `deleteafterinstall`) -- you can't put the files in `{tmp}` or any similar path as the files are very deeply nested and the db installer ends up failing to access some files because the path is too long.

Answer (score 0):

If you use an unpacked installer file, here is what should work absolutely perfect.

SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe /x:%temp%\SQLEXPR_x64_ENU\ /QS /ACTION=Install /SKIPRULES=RebootRequiredCheck /SUPPRESSPRIVACYSTATEMENTNOTICE=1 /IAcceptSQLServerLicenseTerms=1 /SECURITYMODE=SQL /SAPWD=secretPW /ConfigurationFile=ConfigurationFileExpr.ini

In the above command, /x:%temp%\SQLEXPR_x64_ENU\ is the very important switch where it describes the extraction location and with combination to /QS it will show you the progress on screen but will not ask for any input.

You may have to change **%temp%** to appropriate command to grab a windows temporary folder in your installer. The command I have posted is good for command-line execution.

Enjoy! :)